# Regex (ICU) for matching between parentheses

Tags: regex, r, pcre, icu

Looking for some regex which will create a capture group for words occurring within parentheses, ignoring the parentheses themselves. The regex must be either PCRE or ICU.

Input:  `( lakshd  asd___ asa1123 Name : _____)`

Desired Output: `Name`

What I've tried:

`\\((Name|name|NAME)\\)`

`(?<=\\()name|Name|NAME(?=\\))`

`\\(name|Name|NAME\\)`

Comment: What do you mean? You tried to remove the `Name` inside parentheses? I do not get the point of looking for a known word and keep it, it is the same as declaring a variable and assigning a value to it. At any rate, what you are doing can be found with `str_match(s, "(?i)\\([^()]*\\b(Name)\\b[^()]*\\)")`

Comment: Will you have nested levels of parentheses as well?

Comment: You don't have `(Name)` in any case version. I think you could use `\\(.*(Name|name|NAME).*\\)` I don't know `r` but there isn't just a `contains` or `strpos` function out there.

Comment: @revo No nested parentheses are expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I've tried:
>
> `\\((Name|name|NAME)\\)`
> `(?<=\\()name|Name|NAME(?=\\))`
> `\\(name|Name|NAME\\)`

All these patterns look for `name` or `Name` or `NAME` that has a `(` *immediately* before and `)` *right* after, with difference being what is captured or returned as a match. To match some word inside parentheses, you need to use `\([^()]*` before the value you need to get, and `[^()]*\)` after it.

Also, there is no point in extracting something you already know.

So, if you plan to extract the last word from the parentheses, you may use

```
> library(stringr)
> s = "( lakshd  asd___ asa1123 Name : _____)"
> res <- str_match(s, "(?i)\\([^()]*\\b([a-z]\\w*)\\b[^()]*\\)")
> res[,2]
[1] "Name"
```

Note that `str_match` allows accessing *captured* values.

The `(?i)\\([^()]*\\b([a-z]\\w*)\\b[^()]*\\)` pattern matches parentheses and the last whole word from it.

Comment: There is a point to extracting in this way but that is beyond the scope of the question and something I don't need assistance on

Answer (score 0):

If nested levels of parentheses are not likely to happen then looking if current position is going to be followed by a closing parenthesis at the end while an opening parenthesis is supposed to be opened already will do the trick (works with both ICU and PCRE):

```
(Name|name|NAME)(?=[^()]*\))
```

[PCRE live demo](https://regex101.com/r/rM8jR3/1)